# Root user in Fedora 38

Tags: linux, fedora, root, administration, redhat-classic

I recently switched from Windows to Fedora.

While I don't remember if I set any password for root during installation of Fedora but I created one user. Now, if I try to switch from the user to root with su - root, it asks for a password.

How can login to root in this case?

I tried some random passwords but no luck.

Comment: Try with `sudo su - `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't get asked to setup a root password, it's because you
created a user and checked the "Make this user an Admin User" checkbox
and then didn't do the enable root step.

To set a new root password :

```
sudo su -
passwd
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked.